# looking for automatic stress tests framework

Tags: java, tomcat, jmeter, stress-testing

I have a application that is deployed on tomcat container. 
I'm running the jmeter load (x threads with HttpRequests). 
then I'm looking on TPS, latencies, cpu, and memory (through jmx).

I'm looking for a automatic way to do all this, and may be better.
Any good references, blogs, articles, maybe some github sources is appresiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd really need to be more specific about what you would like to automate, running the test, analyzing the results, monitoring your AUT or?

That said, you could try this: https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2. This will automate test execution using remote hosts which can be useful to some people in some scenarios.

Comment: I need some results analysis (tps, latencies ...)

Comment: jmeter does not give this out of the box but it's not so hard to code up a solution. If you use the command line to execute the test then the -l flag tells jmeter where to put the results and then it's simply a matter of writing a post execution processing step that takes this file and analyses it. Eg. we use the shell script above to upload our results to a database and we query them from there using a custom presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm so are you searching for what exactly? I was using JProfiler and it was very efficient for me. I recorded measurement data from my app which i could analyze on the fly and afterwards as well. But i'm not sure if this is what you need. "Automatic stress test". Maybe you could run a bunch of Selenium tests while running JProfiler? Will you use commercial or do you prefer 'free' (sorry for the term) tools?

Have fun anyway :)

Dave